# Import error with atom module

Tags: python, python-2.7, gdata

```
from __future__ import division
import sys, time, os.path, magic
import atom.data, gdata.client, gdata.docs.client, gdata.docs.data
```

The complete code is at http://planzero.org/blog/2012/04/13/uploading_any_file_to_google_docs_with_python

I am working in Ubuntu 14.04 on virtualbox. I am using Python 2.7.6. I have both the atom and the gdata modules installed successfully with latest versions. But my code gives me the following error while importing the modules.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test14.py", line 16, in <module>
    import atom.data, gdata.client, gdata.docs.client, gdata.docs.data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/atom/data.py", line 24, in <module>
    import atom.core
ImportError: No module named core
```

---

I also tried to import the entire atom module instead.

```
import atom, gdata.client, gdata.docs.client, gdata.docs.data
```

Gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test14.py", line 16, in <module>
    import atom, gdata.client, gdata.docs.client, gdata.docs.data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/client.py", line 35, in <module>
    import atom.client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/atom/client.py", line 27, in <module>
    import atom.http_core
ImportError: No module named http_core
```

Both core.py and http_core.py are present at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/atom/. I tried directly importing these modules

```
import atom.http_core, atom.core
```

It worked. So what is going wrong?

Comment: Make sure there is a package name `core` or a module name `core.py` in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/atom/`. Or take the line `import atom.core` out of the file `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/atom/data.py`

Comment: @BiRico: core.py is in that directory. So I tried to comment out the import atom.core statement. data.py throws more errors. This won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that worked for me. Not a solution I would go for if I had a choice, but it did work!

First I copied atom and gdata directories from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` to my working directory. I did this because it made editing any files easier. Python looked for the import modules first in the working directory. And I got permissions on the copied directories and files. Plus I retain the original copy in the original location.

Next I edited the data.py file from atom. I changed the import statement from `import atom.core` to `import core`.

Next I edited the client.py file from atom. I changed the import statement from `import atom.http_core` to `import http_core`.

This seemed to be working as I didn't get any errors at these points anymore. Now I realized that in both of the above instances, import statement tried to import the module as atom.module from inside the atom package. So then I proceeded to change all the instances where `atom.module` was used in the above files to just `module`. The code ran fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same troubles when I was trying to install (Mac OSX 10.10.5, python version 2.7.6). I did the following

1. Uninstall atom (pip uninstall atom) and let `gdata` install it in its `setup.py` file
2. `pip install tlslite`
3. Run the `gdata-python-client-master/tests/run_data_tests.py` file

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/carolinux/gdata-python-client/issues/689)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either the module has errors or you're missing some files. Based on [this](https://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/atom.html) I would suspect the latter.

If you know where the atom module files are(probably in some directory from `PYTHON_PATH`), check if there is an `atom\core.py` file. If not, check the installing instructions(you may have needed to run some script first) or reinstall the module.

If that fails, you can try to comment out the `atom.core` import but it's very likely it is used somewhere in `atom.data` and you will only get more errors.

Comment: core.py exists. And when I try to comment it out from data.py, more errors are thrown. data.py needs to import core.py.

Comment: Is the core.py file in the same `atom` directory as the data.py file and is there an `__init__.py` file inside as well?

Comment: yes. I see an `__init__.py` in atom directory also.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed atom using pip and have tried uninstalling it using pip uninstall and it does not work. Then delete it manually using `sudo rm -rf <path_to_atom>` and then reinstall gdata-python-client using `sudo python setup.py install`